# Objective C: NSDictionnary Unordered

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I receive from an API an array of json format object, so I put it in a NSDictionnary, the problem is that it is not in the same order as the sound received. How to restore order? I tried the line of code below:

```
- (void)connectionManagerDidGotPriceList:(NSDictionary *)prices{
NSArray *sortedKeys = [prices.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]];

NSArray *sortedValues = [prices objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:@""];

list_categories = sortedKeys;
list = sortedValues;
[priceList reloadData];
```

}

But I get this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000399ab20'

How to keep the same order as the sound received in the NSDictionnary?

The Json response from the server:

```
     {
   "status":true,
   "data":{
      "גיהוץ":[
         {
            "PriceListId":9,
            "ItemTypeId":18,
            "JobTypeId":5,
            "price":8.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"חולצה",
            "JobTypeDescription":"גיהוץ",
            "LondryName":""
         },
         {
            "PriceListId":962,
            "ItemTypeId":41,
            "JobTypeId":7,
            "price":40.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"מפה",
            "JobTypeDescription":"כביסה וגיהוץ",
            "LondryName":""
         }
      ],
      "ניקוי יבש":[
         {
            "PriceListId":15,
            "ItemTypeId":18,
            "JobTypeId":6,
            "price":28.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"חולצה",
            "JobTypeDescription":"ניקוי יבש",
            "LondryName":""
         },
         {
            "PriceListId":16,
            "ItemTypeId":19,
            "JobTypeId":6,
            "price":30.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"מכנסים",
            "JobTypeDescription":"ניקוי יבש",
            "LondryName":""
         },
         {
            "PriceListId":835,
            "ItemTypeId":99,
            "JobTypeId":6,
            "price":38.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"סווטשירט",
            "JobTypeDescription":"ניקוי יבש",
            "LondryName":""
         }
      ],
      "כביסה וקיפול":[
         {
            "PriceListId":128,
            "ItemTypeId":22,
            "JobTypeId":8,
            "price":66.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"שק כביסי אחד (עד 6 ק\"ג)",
            "JobTypeDescription":"כביסה וקיפול",
            "LondryName":""
         },
         {
            "PriceListId":956,
            "ItemTypeId":104,
            "JobTypeId":8,
            "price":99.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"שק כביסי אחד (עד 9 ק\"ג)",
            "JobTypeDescription":"כביסה וקיפול",
            "LondryName":""
         }
      ],
      "כביסה עדינה":[
         {
            "PriceListId":855,
            "ItemTypeId":102,
            "JobTypeId":83,
            "price":9.00,
            "LondryId":0,
            "ItemTypeDescription":"כביסה עדינה וייבוש בתליה יח'",
            "JobTypeDescription":"כביסה עדינה",
            "LondryName":""
         }
      ]
   },
   "message":""
}
```

Comment: Did you receive an array or a dictionary?  If it is an array, how did you put in in a dictionary?  Dictionaries are unordered.  Perhaps you can edit your question to show the JSON you are receiving and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Look my edit please, I want to keep this order

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this :

```
NSMutableArray *dataArr = @[].mutableCopy;
for (int i = 0 ; i < data.allKeys.count; i++) {
    NSString *key = data.allKeys[i];
    NSMutableDictionary *dataForKey = [data[key] mutableCopy];
    dataForKey[@"Key"] = key;
    [dataArr addObject:dataForKey];
}

NSSortDescriptor *desc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Key" ascending:YES];
dataArr =[dataArr sortUsingDescriptors:@[desc]];
```

You can get the cast data from you json from server into NSDictionary and then use this loop to add all the items to an array and then sort those items using the Key.